# Sending the return key to an emulated console application

Tags: delphi

I'm using delphi to add an graphical interface to a console application.
The problem is when the console application asks for input.
I would normally type in my input and press enter to make it accept my string, but I don't know how to do this.

I'm using this library as a "wrapper" over the console application, it uses pipes for the input and output streams.
http://koders.com/delphi/fidDB05C6361540F62D532FC7C960D4111CE3AAEDB3.aspx?s=proxy

I've tried things like WriteToConsoleApp(#04); to send an EOT, which is Control-D. This would normally work but in this case it doesn't do anything.
I've also tried WriteToConsoleApp(#13); WriteToConsoleApp(#13#10);, but none of these solutions work.

If you have any advice I would be grateful.

Comment: The referenced library doesn't work on Delphi Versions over 2007

Comment: And actually is a shame, since it is a really nice library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SendMessage or PostMessage function to send string/key to console application.
For example;

```
SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_CHAR, Ord('A'), 0);//sends 'A' to the window
```

or

```
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);//sends Return to the window
```

Comment: The console program was created with the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag. There's no place to send those messages.

Comment: Maybe I can change it so that the input stream is on a hidden window.